# How to make WebMatrix recognize CakePhp templates (*.ctp) as php?

Tags: cakephp, webmatrix

This question is specifically about Microsoft's WebMatrix as an IDE
How can I make it recognize files with the extension ctp which are cake templates as php and open them localy and format and colorize the source code?

Answer (score 3):

Little unsupported hack here :)  Open up this file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\config\filetypes.xml

Look for .php in the file - you should find something that looks like this:

`<FileType extension=".php;.phtml">`

Modify that line, and add your file extension.  Next time you open WebMatrix it should treat that file as PHP.